# How to open all top level accordions but keep nested accordions closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have one accordion where all items have another nested accordion. I'm trying to open the first level of accordions by clicking on the button, without opening nested accordions.

I would like to open all "Groups"-accordions and keep sub-accordions "Count 1" and "Count 2" closed.

How can I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Collapse inner groups:
  $('#p-lists').on('hide', function(e) {
    // Force a collapse (.hide() doesn't seem to work properly here but is unnecessary anyway):
    $(e.target).find('.accordion-body')
      .removeClass('in')
      .attr('style', '');
  });

  // Make sure parent groups are also opened:
  $('#p-lists').on('show', function(e) {

    var $parent = $(e.target).parents('.accordion-body');
    // Collapse all siblings:
    $parent.parents('.accordion-group')
      .prevAll('.accordion-group').find('.accordion-body').collapse('hide')
      .nextAll('.accordion-group').find('.accordion-body').collapse('hide');
    // Then open THIS parent:
    $parent.collapse('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<h3>Accordion test</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#p-counts-2">Open counts 2</button>
<div class="accordion" id="p-lists">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-lists" href="#p-lists-1">
        <h5>Group 1</h5>
      </a>

    </div>
    <div id="p-lists-1" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">Body p1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-lists" href="#p-lists-2">
        <h5>Group 2</h5>
      </a>

    </div>
    <div id="p-lists-2" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <h4>Inner accordion</h4>

        <!-- Start of inner -->
        <div class="accordion" id="p-counts">
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-counts" href="#p-counts-1">
                <h5>Counts 1</h5>
              </a>

            </div>
            <div id="p-counts-1" class="accordion-body collapse">
              <div class="accordion-inner">Counts p1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-counts" href="#p-counts-2">
                <h5>Counts 2</h5>
              </a>

            </div>
            <div id="p-counts-2" class="accordion-body collapse">
              <div class="accordion-inner">Counts p2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of inner -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-lists" href="#p-lists-3">
        <h5>Group 3</h5>
      </a>

    </div>
    <div id="p-lists-3" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">Body p3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PugwashXP/xge5uc1v/38/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, 
on your button click, we check if any of the sub-accordions have been opened, if yes, we close them;
on the normal accordion panel click, we wouldn't intentionally close the sub-accordions;

**Snippet** below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myBtn').click(function() {
    ($('#group1').hasClass('collapsed')) ? $("a#group1").trigger('click'): '';
    ($('#group2').hasClass('collapsed')) ? $("a#group2").trigger('click'): '';
    ($('#group3').hasClass('collapsed')) ? $("a#group3").trigger('click'): '';
    $("a.accordion-toggle-inner:not('.collapsed')").each(function() {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#group1,
#group2,
#group3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <button id='myBtn' type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse"> open the first level of
            accordions by clicking on the button, without opening nested accordions</button>


  <div class="accordion">
    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id='group1' href="#p-lists-1">
      <h5>Group 1</h5>
    </a>
    <div id="p-lists-1" class="accordion-body collapse">
      Body p1
    </div>


    <div class="accordion-group">
      <a id='group2' class="accordion-toggle  collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#p-lists-2">
        <h5>Group 2</h5>
      </a>

      <div id="p-lists-2" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          <h4>Inner accordion</h4>

          <!-- Start of inner -->
          <div class="accordion" id="p-counts">
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed accordion-toggle-inner" data-toggle="collapse" href="#p-counts-1">
                  <h5>Counts 1</h5>
                </a>

              </div>
              <div id="p-counts-1" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">Counts p1</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed accordion-toggle-inner" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-counts" href="#p-counts-2">
              <h5>Counts 2</h5>
            </a>
            <div id="p-counts-2" class="accordion-body collapse">
              Counts p2
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of inner -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="accordion-toggle  collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id='group3' href="#p-lists-3">
      <h5>Group 3</h5>
    </a>
    <div id="p-lists-3" class="accordion-body collapse"> Body p3</div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**: in light of questioner's comment above

Comment: it's not really what I asked. I need to open all collapsible Groups 1,2,3 simultaneously by one click on the button. And collapsible divs "Counts 1" and "Counts 2"  under "Group 2" should be stay closed

Comment: yes it works. exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!